# Problema con mi base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos para un proyecto escolar y me da el siguiente error:

(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Por favor ayuda, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `bibliotecaFastDev` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (
  `isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `n_pags` INT NOT NULL,
  `precio_ref` INT NOT NULL,
  `anio_publ` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`editorial`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`editorial` (
  `idEditorial` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Libro_isbn` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEditorial`),
  INDEX `fk_Editorial_Libro_idx` (`Libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Editorial_Libro`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`numeroSerie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`numeroSerie` (
  `n_serie` INT NOT NULL,
  `Libro_isbn` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`n_serie`),
  INDEX `fk_NumeroSerie_Libro1_idx` (`Libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_NumeroSerie_Libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`autor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`autor` (
  `idAutor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoMat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoPat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Libro_isbn` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAutor`),
  INDEX `fk_Autor_Libro1_idx` (`Libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Autor_Libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`categoria`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`categoria` (
  `idCategoria` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Libro_isbn` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategoria`),
  INDEX `fk_Categoria_Libro1_idx` (`Libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Categoria_Libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`idioma`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`idioma` (
  `id_idioma` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idioma` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Libro_isbn` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_idioma`),
  INDEX `fk_Idioma_Libro1_idx` (`Libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Idioma_Libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`distribuidor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`distribuidor` (
  `rut` VARCHAR(11) NULL,
  `nombreEmpresa` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `anioVenta` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rut`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (
  `rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoMat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoPat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `fechaNace` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rut`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`correoCliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`correoCliente` (
  `id_correoCliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `correo` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  `cliente_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_correoCliente`),
  INDEX `fk_correoCliente_cliente1_idx` (`cliente_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_correoCliente_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`telefonoCliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`telefonoCliente` (
  `id_telefonoCliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `telefono` INT NOT NULL,
  `cliente_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_telefonoCliente`),
  INDEX `fk_telefonoCliente_cliente1_idx` (`cliente_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_telefonoCliente_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (
  `rut` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoMat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoPat` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `fechaContrato` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rut`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`correoTrabajador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`correoTrabajador` (
  `id_correoTrabajador` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `correo` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  `trabajador_rut` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_correoTrabajador`),
  INDEX `fk_correoTrabajador_trabajador1_idx` (`trabajador_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_correoTrabajador_trabajador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trabajador_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`telefonoTrabajador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`telefonoTrabajador` (
  `id_telefonoTrabajador` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `telefono` INT NOT NULL,
  `trabajador_rut` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_telefonoTrabajador`),
  INDEX `fk_telefonoTrabajador_trabajador1_idx` (`trabajador_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_telefonoTrabajador_trabajador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trabajador_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`direccionTrabajador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`direccionTrabajador` (
  `id_direccionTrabajador` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  `trabajador_rut` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_direccionTrabajador`),
  INDEX `fk_direccionTrabajador_trabajador1_idx` (`trabajador_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_direccionTrabajador_trabajador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trabajador_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`factura` (
  `folio` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `precioNeto` INT NOT NULL,
  `precioMasIVA` INT NOT NULL,
  `costoIVA` INT NOT NULL,
  `fechaCompra` DATE NOT NULL,
  `horaCompra` TIME NOT NULL,
  `distribuidor_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`folio`),
  INDEX `fk_factura_distribuidor1_idx` (`distribuidor_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_factura_distribuidor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`distribuidor_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`distribuidor` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`metodoPago_factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`metodoPago_factura` (
  `id_MetPagoFact` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `metodoPago` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `factura_folio` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_MetPagoFact`),
  INDEX `fk_metodoPago_factura_factura1_idx` (`factura_folio` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_metodoPago_factura_factura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`factura_folio`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`factura` (`folio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`boleta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`boleta` (
  `folio` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `precioNeto` INT NOT NULL,
  `precioMasIVA` INT NOT NULL,
  `costoIVA` INT NOT NULL,
  `fechaVenta` DATE NOT NULL,
  `horaVenta` TIME NOT NULL,
  `cliente_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`folio`),
  INDEX `fk_boleta_cliente1_idx` (`cliente_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_boleta_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`metodoPago_boleta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`metodoPago_boleta` (
  `id_MetPagoBol` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `metodoPago` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `boleta_folio` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_MetPagoBol`),
  INDEX `fk_metodoPago_boleta_boleta1_idx` (`boleta_folio` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_metodoPago_boleta_boleta1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`boleta_folio`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`boleta` (`folio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`arriendo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`arriendo` (
  `idarriendo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `costoTotal` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `fechaDevEst` DATE NOT NULL,
  `fechaEntrega` DATE NOT NULL,
  `costo` INT NOT NULL,
  `libro_isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `trabajador_rut` INT NOT NULL,
  `cliente_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idarriendo`),
  INDEX `fk_arriendo_libro1_idx` (`libro_isbn` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_arriendo_trabajador1_idx` (`trabajador_rut` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_arriendo_cliente1_idx` (`cliente_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arriendo_libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arriendo_trabajador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trabajador_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arriendo_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`arriendo_multa`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`arriendo_multa` (
  `id_multa` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `diasRetraso` INT NOT NULL,
  `costoExtra` INT NOT NULL,
  `arriendo_idarriendo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multa`),
  INDEX `fk_arriendo_multa_arriendo1_idx` (`arriendo_idarriendo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arriendo_multa_arriendo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`arriendo_idarriendo`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`arriendo` (`idarriendo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`compra`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`compra` (
  `idcompra` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factura_folio` INT NOT NULL,
  `distribuidor_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcompra`),
  INDEX `fk_compra_factura1_idx` (`factura_folio` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_compra_distribuidor1_idx` (`distribuidor_rut` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compra_factura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`factura_folio`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`factura` (`folio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compra_distribuidor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`distribuidor_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`distribuidor` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`librosComprados`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`librosComprados` (
  `id_librosComprados` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cantidad` INT NOT NULL,
  `libro_isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `compra_idcompra` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_librosComprados`),
  INDEX `fk_librosComprados_libro1_idx` (`libro_isbn` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_librosComprados_compra1_idx` (`compra_idcompra` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_librosComprados_libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_librosComprados_compra1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`compra_idcompra`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`compra` (`idcompra`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`venta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`venta` (
  `idventa` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente_rut` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `trabajador_rut` INT NOT NULL,
  `boleta_folio` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idventa`),
  INDEX `fk_venta_cliente1_idx` (`cliente_rut` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_venta_trabajador1_idx` (`trabajador_rut` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_venta_boleta1_idx` (`boleta_folio` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_venta_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`cliente` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_venta_trabajador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`trabajador_rut`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`trabajador` (`rut`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_venta_boleta1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`boleta_folio`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`boleta` (`folio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bibliotecaFastDev`.`librosVendidos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bibliotecaFastDev`.`librosVendidos` (
  `id_librosVendidos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cantidad` INT NOT NULL,
  `venta_idventa` INT NOT NULL,
  `libro_isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_librosVendidos`),
  INDEX `fk_librosVendidos_venta1_idx` (`venta_idventa` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_librosVendidos_libro1_idx` (`libro_isbn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_librosVendidos_venta1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`venta_idventa`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`venta` (`idventa`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_librosVendidos_libro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`libro_isbn`)
    REFERENCES `bibliotecaFastDev`.`libro` (`isbn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Hola Charulo, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar una medalla). También lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] (sería más fácil ayudarte si en lugar de poner todo el código que genera tu base de datos solo pusieras el de las tablas relacionadas en el problema y la línea en la que ocurre). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El error es debido a que declaras como clave foranea columnas de distinto tipo.

Si te fijas en `bibliotecaFastDev.libro` declaras `isbn VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL` luego en `bibliotecaFastDev.editorial` declaras `Libro_isbn INT NOT NULL` por lo que genera un error al crear una clave foranea de una columna tipo VARCHAR a otra tipo INT

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Editorial_Libro 
FOREIGN KEY (Libro_isbn) REFERENCES bibliotecaFastDev.libro (isbn) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Y así en todas las tablas, revisalas.