# Error #1005 al exportar DB

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Hola estoy exportando una base de datos de workbench a phpmyadmin y me sale este error #1005:

```
#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `medico`.`citas` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Medico`.`citas` (
  `id_citas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha_cita` DATE NOT NULL,
  `dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral` INT NOT NULL,
  `especialidades_id_especialidades` INT NOT NULL,
  `personas_id_cedula` INT NOT NULL,
  `medico_id_medico` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_citas`),
  INDEX `fk_citas_dias_laboral1_idx` (`dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_especialidades1_idx` (`especialidades_id_especialidades` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_personas1_idx` (`personas_id_cedula` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_medico1_idx` (`medico_id_medico` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_dias_laboral1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`dias_laboral` (`id_dias_laboral`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_especialidades1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`especialidades_id_especialidades`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`especialidades` (`id_especialidades`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_personas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`personas_id_cedula`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`personas` (`id_cedula`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_medico1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`medico_id_medico`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`medico` (`id_medico`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Sin no das más datos poco se puede hacer... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167988/problema-con-mi-base-de-datos

Answer (score 0):

este es el codigo es mas grande pero las otras tablas le pasa lo mismo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Medico`.`citas` (
  `id_citas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha_cita` DATE NOT NULL,
  `dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral` INT NOT NULL,
  `especialidades_id_especialidades` INT NOT NULL,
  `personas_id_cedula` INT NOT NULL,
  `medico_id_medico` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_citas`),
  INDEX `fk_citas_dias_laboral1_idx` (`dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_especialidades1_idx` (`especialidades_id_especialidades` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_personas1_idx` (`personas_id_cedula` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_citas_medico1_idx` (`medico_id_medico` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_dias_laboral1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dias_laboral_id_dias_laboral`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`dias_laboral` (`id_dias_laboral`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_especialidades1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`especialidades_id_especialidades`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`especialidades` (`id_especialidades`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_personas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`personas_id_cedula`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`personas` (`id_cedula`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_citas_medico1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`medico_id_medico`)
    REFERENCES `Medico`.`medico` (`id_medico`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Por favor. Para añadir información a tu pregunta, edita la pregunta. Aquí sólo van las respuestas

Comment: lo tomare en cuanta Muchas Gracias sr Alfredo